# Pivoting and transforming data in JS

Tags: javascript, data-structures

I want to do *client-side* data transformation in JavaScript, for instance I'd like to transform:

```
[
  {env:'test', name:'something'},
  {env:'test', name:'else'},
  {env:'prod', name:'entirely'},
]
```

into:

```
{
  envs: [
    { name:'test', 'things': [ {name: 'something'}, {'name': 'else'} ] },
    { name:'prod', 'things': [ {name: 'entirely'} ] }
  ]
}
```

What is the best way to do this? A library or brute-force? In Python I'd use list comprehension, something like:

```
in_data = [...]
d = defaultdict(list)
for t in in_data:
    d[t['env']] += [t]
out_data = { 'envs': [{'name':k, 'things':v} for k,v in d.items()] }
```

Could I use JS `map` or arrow functions to accomplish the same, or perhaps using some library? It would be good if it runs in standard Chrome (without manually having to enable some ES2015 or the like).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it by doing something like this:

```js
var data = [
  {env:'test', name:'something'},
  {env:'test', name:'else'},
  {env:'prod', name:'entirely'},
];


var groups = data.reduce(function(acc, obj) {
  acc[obj.env] = acc[obj.env] || [];
  acc[obj.env].push(obj);
  return acc;
}, {});

var result = {
  envs: Object.keys(groups).map(function(key) {
    return {
      name: key,
      things: groups[key].map(function(obj) {
        return {
          name: obj.name
        }
      })
    }
  })
};

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Underscore lib

```
function organizeObject(b){
   var a = _.map(_.groupBy(b, "env"), function(v, i){
        return {name: i, "things": _.map(v, function(i){return {name: i.name} })}
   });
   return {envs : a}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the benefit of Set's unique keys to get test and prod then looped the set with this code here.

First create `new Set(data.map(item => item.env));` a new set. Then an empty envs array. Then loop, push and map/filter the items into the envs array

```
set.forEach((item) => {
   envs.push({ name: item, things: data.map(d => { 
    if (d.env === item) {
        return {name: d.name}
    }
    return false;
   }).filter((f) => typeof f === "object")}) 
});
```

Comment: I added the code into a function to show how it would work in the wild..


function doit(data) {
    const envs = []
    const set = new Set(data.map(item => item.env))
    set.forEach((item) => {
   envs.push({ name: item, things: data.map(d => { 
    if (d.env === item) {
        return {name: d.name}
    }
    return false;
   }).filter((f) => typeof f === "object")}) 
});
    return envs
}